# How can I create a bootable DVD iso from a USB drive?

Tags: usb, dvd, iso-image, bootloader

There seems to be a lot of questions / answers about doing the reverse, but not as much info for USB -> DVD.

**Problem**

I created a bootable USB drive using YUMI.

The USB drive is working great, and contains the following:

- Linux Mint 13
- Linux Mint Debian
- Debian 6
- Ubuntu 12.04.1
- Fedora 17

A bit of a mix of DVD and Live versions.

I have a spindle of DVD+R DL blank DVD's. I would like to create a bootable .iso from this USB drive so I can burn multiple copies of it to pass around to friends!

I've created an iso using Folder2ISO, but it coastered my DVD because it wasn't bootable. I don't really want to waste a whole spindle!

How would you go about doing such a thing?

Comment: Why can't you use YUMI to create the iso itself?  You sure the dvd wasn't bootable for other reasons?

Comment: I don't think YUMI supports creating iso - just creating USB drives? I'm unsure if it wasn't bootable for other reasons hrrmm. Is there something special I need to do with the USB's boot sector? Or should Folder2ISO have done everything required? Thanks!

Comment: Also, the iso itself wouldn't boot when I tried it within VirtualBox.

Comment: " I don't really want to waste a whole spindle!" Experiment with a DVD+RW.

Comment: Have you booted into Windows or any other OS and browsed the USB drive for ISOs? I have used other programs that do the same as YUMI and they copy the ISO to a directory and boot them. Just a thought. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Journeyman - I didn't know how to mark it this way.  But the questions and my answer are identical.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it in reverse, but let us know if this works:

1. Download and install [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com).
2. Follow [this guide](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=1779) to enter and set appropriate options for *Build Mode*.
3. Follow the steps indicated below to first *Create Boot Image* from the USB drive, ensure the *Make Image Bootable* option is checked, set the *Emulation Type* to *Hard Disk* and select the previously created *Boot Image*.
4. Burn, test and report back!

   [image: ImgBurn - Advanced - Create Bootable Disc]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I actually tried this earlier and when it created the boot image from my USB drive, it literally copied the entire contents of the USB drive and the resulting iso was 13+ GB large. This was because it appended the entire boot image onto the same files and folders I added from the USB drive (if you get me). The resulting iso still wouldnt boot in virtualbox or qemu, and naturally due to the size I couldnt burn it onto a DL DVD. Thanks anyways though!

Answer (score 2):

On newer version of [ImgBurn](http://filehippo.com/download_imgburn/) just go to:

1. Build > Mode
2. Advanced > Extract Boot Image > Inform path and filename to .iso

[image]

Comment: I found this information useful too: https://forum.imgburn.com/topic/26101-bootable-disc-incorrect-function/ I needed to add the location of my etfsboot.com file in Boot Image, and change Sectors to Load to 8 (for a Win7 iso) and make sure I had added my bootable USB containing Windows folders in the Source list

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB in VirtualBox and encountered the same issue.  It turned out I had to create a virtual disk that referenced the USB drive, then assign that virtual disk to the virtual machine.  I found the instructions to do this here: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-boot-from-usb-in-virtualbox/

Also, I did note that there's a typo in his command line syntax.  There should be a space between "-rawdisk" and "\".  But otherwise it worked like a charm!

Comment: Welcome to Super User SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://superuser.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score -1):

Use "Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.9" Its free and simple to use.. just need an ISO of the version of Ubuntu and a USB drive.  This can also make a Windows usb installer.  Best program I have found for this.

http://www.techspot.com/downloads/downloadnow/6153/?evp=87ab07200047ce3cd94b4bda0e971dd9&file=

Check it out.

Comment: Your answer puts an ISO onto a USB drive. The OP is asking for putting a bootable USB drive into an ISO file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://superuser.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy to read a bootable USB to an ISO: Just use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) - it does precisely what you are asking for.

The program is self-explanatory.

Here is a search that has links to reviews and instructions:  [Rufus search results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=rufus%20copy%20iso%20to%20usb)

Then you can use your favorite ISO burner to get it on a DVD.  I use [CDburnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) on all my machines, from Vista to Win8.1

It has only one limitation:   It only works with optical disks.  That's why you need Rufus to read the stick first.

Comment: OP is asking how to create an ISO from USB. The link provided in this answer leads to a page stating that Rufus does the opposite.