# Can't burn USB image onto a CD/DVD

Tags: dvd, burning, fat32, recovery

I made a Windows 8 Recovery USB drive. I wanted to back it as RAW as possible to a DVD, whether or not I could use this DVD as I could the original USB drive. The DVD is just the permanent copy of the Recovery, as the USB drive is usually used to transfer files.

The utility I used is PowerISO for the whole job. I made an image of the original Windows Recovery drive (named recovery.img, below) by going "Tools" > "Make Usb drive image file". Later when I open recovery.img in PowerISO, I see that the USB partition is within some volume:

[image]

Naturally, I choose to "Import"

When I go to "Burn" > "Image file". I get this message:

[image]

What's going on? Is it because the partition is FAT32? What is a direct & most way raw way to burn this to a DVD? I'm not up to extracting all the files & folders in recovery.img & then doing UDF burn to the DVD.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new recovery DVD by running `recdisc.exe`?

Comment: Just typed it in "Run" & it's not recognized. I Googled & found this invokes creating a Windows Repair Disc. Repair Disc is an older approach, targeting CD/DVDs, used up until Win7 or something, but now dropped. It only allows restores of the Windows install. Recovery Media (USB) is more like an installation drive.

Comment: @Dehbop What exactly is on the recovery drive? WinRE, or something else?  If it's WinRE, see the steps at the very bottom of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1482599/529800) within _Custom_ under _DISM & ImageX Prerequisites_, which will allow you to create a bootable ISO of WinRE using `Oscdimg.exe` _(if you want a true recovery drive, you may also wish to check out [Easy2Boot](http://www.easy2boot.com/))_

Comment: @JW0914 Seems very thorough, but I'm more concerned with just burning the image as RAW as possible to a DVD. So I can put away the darn hard copy & not bother with it anymore. If the need arises someday to make the DVD bootable, then I know where to pick right off because I made it as RAW as I could.

Comment: So really, just tell me how to convert this FAT32 or strip it for optical drvie burning, coz I wanna see flames.

Comment: @Dehbop You need to use `oscdimg.exe`.  Please review it's [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options)

Comment: See this.....https://superuser.com/a/1200358/40928

Comment: @Moab I've never tried that with WinRE media, but there's a high likelihood that will not work as Microsoft requires WinRE images to be created with specific parameters for an ISO which the USB WinRE media does not have.  There's only one correct way of creating a WinRE ISO and it's via `oscdimg.exe`.  AFAIK, a bootable WinRE ISO cannot be created from USB media... it's not that simple.

Comment: We will never know until someone tries.

Comment: @Moab Great point =]  I can build a WinPE image when I have time tomorrow to verify, but IIRC, the last time I tried to create an ISO of the WinPE build folder _(w/o utilizing `oscdimg`)_, I was never able to get it to boot unless it was created with `oscdimg`.

Comment: I'll take a quick gloss over this oscdimg. Breaks the habit, but maybe I'll just UDF burn recovery.img as a file in a DVD. Works just as well when re-creating a bootable USB drive.